# GPRS connection still connected while receiving phone call?

Tags: android

Suppose one application is running which is using GPRS connection. If in between that if call comes what will happened with that GPRS connection?? It still persist or it is get disconnected??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, for GPRS and EDGE the data connection cannot be used while a call is ongoing. It is a limitation of the protocol. For 3G (UMTS/HSDPA), concurrent connections are however possible AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for replay.. So we can not use GPRS connection while call is going. So, the GPRS connection get disconnected and we have to connect it again?? or it is suspended??